# How to correctly do matrices input in java

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a problem.

I am trying to make a program where a user will type in

r=row
c=column
and after that 0's and 1's as long as the matric is full

So it will create a picture .... r*v ...., filled with char's 1's and 0's.

Those 1's represent blocks.
Now the program should output how many blocks are in that picture?
(00010011110 - example for the first row of random matrix)- that would print out 2

I am struggling to correctly do the input of that program and after that count the number of those blocks.

This is what I had been trying so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Blocks{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

        int rowNum=sc.nextInt();            //number of rows
        int columnNum=sc.nextInt();         //number of columns

        int blocks=0;
        char[][] matrix=new char[rowNum][columnNum];


        for (int a = 0; a < rowNum; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b < columnNum; b++) {
                char[] row= sc.next().toCharArray();

           for(int i=0; i<matrix.length;i++) {
            if(row[i]=='1'){
                blocks++;
                if(row[i+1]=='1') {
                blocks--;
            }
        }   
    }
}


    }   
}
```

Comment: why 2 for (00010011110 - example for the first row of random matrix)- that would print out 2?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: another example:
r=2
c=4
0010
1100
1111
0101

this would print out 5. Because it only looks for 1's in that matrix and 1's make a block. 11 is a block size 2. 1111 is a block size 4...and so on. And thr above example has 3 blocks. One in the first row,another in the second, then once again one in the third and 
2 blocks in the forth row

Comment: The problem is that I can't even do the input correctly. How do I keep asking the user to give me those numbers(0's and 1's) until the matrix is full.

Comment: The blocks are groups of one or more adjacent elements with the value
1.

Comment: Why can't you simply store the previous input number i.e. 0 or 1. Let's suppose, you have got 1, now keep getting input and when it's 0, you can increment the counter for block (if that is your variable name) and keeps on moving like this for each row. Remember to reset the variable in which you are placing the previous number after each row.

Comment: Mr.777  Iam not sure exactly what you mean. Could your way be still working on what I am trying to do?

Comment: You actually want to get the correct number of blocks, right? If that's so, try the solution i have provided after you are getting the input for each row and column.

Comment: So your solution is to walk through the matrix and then look for 1's and until there is 0 keep counting..then do blocks++, when it hits 0? but how do I keep getting input while doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
char ch[][];
 int rowNum=sc.nextInt();           
 int columnNum=sc.nextInt();
 ch=new char[rowNum][columnNum];
 for (int a = 0; a < rowNum; a++) 
        for (int b = 0; b < columnNum; b++) 
            ch[a][b]= sc.next();
  int i=0;j=0;
 for (int a = 0; a < (rowNum*columnNum); a++) 
  {
             row[a]=ch[i][j];
             i++;
             if(i==rowNum)
                  j++;
  }
```

This may do the trick

```
if(row[i]=='1'){    
            if(row[i+1]=='0') 
            blocks++;
        }
```

Comment: this is only first part of taking in the input

Comment: Kindly format & explain it properly or there will be a lot of down votes

Comment: Ya sorry for the trouble

Comment: This gives me an error when trying to compile...  incompatible types: char[] cannot be converted to char

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
int blocks = 0;
char[][] matrix = new char[rowNum][columnNum];


int nbrOfBlocks = 0;
for (int a = 0; a < rowNum; a++) {
  matrix[a] = sc.next().toCharArray();

  int index = 0;
  while (index < matrix[a].length) {

    if (matrix[a][index] == '1') {
      ++nbrOfBlocks;
      while (index < matrix[a].length && matrix[a][index] == '1') {
        ++index;
      }
    }

    ++index;
  }
}

System.out.println(nbrOfBlocks);
```

Comment: What depth first search has to do with this simple problem?

Comment: Initially the question didn't make it clear that blocks were only formed within a row and in the case of such blocks DFS would be a good solution.

Comment: @Simon blocks can also be formed within colums 

00100/
00100/
10000/ 

has 2 blocks...

Comment: @Simon Thank you! But how would this work if the blocks were in a column...or if the blocks were perfect rectangles

I will add more info in the post...you are great!